# Can't find specific string of text that exists (Notepad++ regex)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to find and replace certain Youtube links from a list. This is what I want to find:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T[^\s"><]*
```

But even though lines like that exist, it says it can't find them. I can only search if I remove the `v=T`. I don't know how regex works, so there's probably some issue there?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your file ?

Answer (score 1):

`?` is a special character in regex. It means "zero or one".

I don't know if they've fixed it yet, but I remember escaping to be painful in Notepad++, so I'd suggest `[?]` there.

Comment: OP wants to match a literal `?`

Comment: My bad, it seems that I should stop lurking around SO :)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to escape the `?` character using a backslash `\`.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=T[^\s"><]*
```

As a side note, `http://www.youtube.com/watch\?v=\w*` should be good enough to match any YouTube video URL.